# How do I update like dislike vote in database without throwing an error?

Tags: python, database, mongodb

I'm making an online business jargon dictionary using MongoDB. I want to make it possible to vote terms up and down. I'm getting to grips with CRUD, but I'm a bit stumped on the syntax for updating part of a record.

I have this template:

```
    <div class="col s-12 m-9 l10 text-center cyan-text text-darken-3 dict-cta">
        <a href="{{url_for('like', entry_id=entry._id)}}">
        <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
    </div>
```

The logic is that when "like" is clicked, the code should pull `"love_percent"` from a dictionary, convert to integer (or provide value zero if not present), add 1, convert to string and update within the same `ObjectID`. This is the code I wrote for that route:

```
    @app.route("/like/<entry_id>")
    def like(entry_id):
        entry = mongo.db.jargon.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(entry_id)})
        value = int(entry["love_percent"][0])
        value += 1
        value = str(value)
        entry.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(entry_id)},
            {"$set": {
                love_percent[0]: value
            }})
        return render_template("jargon.html")
```

I tried using just update or storing the integer but that seemed to fix it. A friend suggested `update_one` but I'm basically a bit confused and lost.

Can anyone suggest what I'm missing here or a better approach?

(I'm aware that this doesn't prevent multiple votes from the same user; that functionality can come later.)

The dictionary is being staged on Heroku here and I have pushed it through with the bug: http://jargon-unchained.herokuapp.com/get_jargon

I get the following Error on Traceback:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'update_one'

The repository for this code is in Github: https://github.com/dandavies23/jargon-unchained

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example; and make sure that you [show complete error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146). We can only help you with errors that we can actually see.

Comment: Please also keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*, and note the [edits I have made to your post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) to keep to a strict Q&A style. This does not completely fix the post; I cannot explain for you what is going wrong when you run the code (because only you know that, so far), and I don't know for sure what library you are using to implement the web server (Django? Flask? Something else? You should tell us; it's also not clear why you seem to think the problem has to do with MongoDB instead).

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel I appreciate the feedback and guidance. I'll take a look at your answer, read the guidelines and come back. Before I apply your answer I can answer some of the direct questions you ask. I'm using Flask. I'm sure it's not a problem with MongoDB but my expression of the code.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question.

You need to change the following:

1. As you have only like an option right now

```
value = int(entry["love_percent"])
```

2. You are changing in the database, so use the following command.

```
mongo.db.jargon.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(entry_id)},
            {"$set": {
                "love_percent" : value
            }})
```

Do try and tell issues faced in the comments.

Comment: Thank you. The error message I get in Traceback is 
NameError: name 'love_percent' is not defined

Comment: can u check this once.

Comment: @dandavies23 What is your schema. Can you share one document?

Comment: Thanks for the advice I removed the [0] I thought it was returning 0 if no value existed. That worked but threw up another error with the template build which was confusing me.  See Answer below and thanks for taking the time to check.

Comment: My code worked right? If yes, please upvote and mark it as the correct answer for future references.

Answer (score 0):

Removed [0] which I thought wasn't a position but a default integer. Resolved issue giving each entry a default of 55 on data-entry.

I was also re-rendering the template with a term I hadn't defined within the function. Fixed with a redirect.

```
def like(entry_id):
    entry = mongo.db.jargon.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(entry_id)})
    value = int(entry["love_percent"])
    value += 1
    value = str(value)
    mongo.db.jargon.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(entry_id)},
        {"$set": {
            "love_percent": value
        }})
    return redirect(url_for("get_jargon"))
```